# How to find the maximum of opening in all orientations at a point in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, orientation, line, morphological-analysis

I need a bit of help. I am trying to segment out sort of zig-zag patterns in an image. I've an algorithm for this. For that I'm opening the image with a line structuring element. I want to perform repeated opening of the image using the line strel at various angles and find maximum of them at each pixel.

Following is a code snippet:

```
    while(i<360)
         se=strel('line',17,i);
         i=i+15;
         img=imopen(img,se);
    end;
```

Any help with the implementation will be appreciated.

Comment: What you have said in your question is exactly describing what the code is doing.  Can you show us what the image looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to get maximum for each pixel from a stack of "opened" images?

```
% I assume the img is a 2D image (e.g. gray-scale one)
stack = [];

while(i<360)
         se=strel('line',17,i);
         i=i+15;
         stack(:,:, end+1) =imopen(img,se);
end;
```

The opened images will stack up in the stack matrix. Then to find maximum at each pixel, you can just search for maximum in 3th dimension:

```
max_pixels = max(stack, 3);
```

Comment: Actually my code is fine too. I just needed to find the supremum and infimum of the openings in all directions.
This is not giving me the required result but thanks anyways :)

Comment: @LunaLove: Consider placing your own answer and accepting it.  This signals the SO community that you no longer need any help